# Plural "les" verb usage: "est" or "sont"?

Tags: verbes, pluriel, questions

In any sentence with plural objects, such as:

> Les sandwichs...

Would I use the *être* plural *sont*, or the object standard third person *est*.

> Les sandwichs sont bon.

or:

> Les sandwichs est bon.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sont".

You never use "est" with plural.

And because "les sandwichs" are the subject, you also need to add an "s" to "bon"

> Les sandwichs sont bons.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike English, French has six different conjugations. It has three for singular subjects, and three for plural subjects. They are pretty straightforward:

- First person singular ("je"; I)
- Second person singular ("tu"; singular you)
- Third person singular ("il", "elle", "on", any singular object; he and she)
- First person plural ("nous"; we)
- Second person plural ("vous"; plural you)
- Third person plural ("ils", "elles", any plural object; they)

So you're right that "est" is third person, but it is third person *singular*. Because your subject is third person *plural*, you need to use "sont".

> Les sandwichs sont bons.